# How Do I Search Deeply Inside A Map, Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm very new to Java. I have written code that uses a Red Black tree :

```
            TreeMap test = new TreeMap();
            Map mainMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map tempMap = new HashMap<>();
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();


            tempMap.put("Visa Credit Card",447747);
            list.add(421323);
            list.add(421630);
            list.add(455451);
            list.add(469375);
            tempMap.put("Visa Debit card",list);

            tempMap.put("Master Card Credit Card",523951);
            tempMap.put("Master Debit Card",5399);

            mainMap.put("ICCI",tempMap);
            mainMap.put("Next",1234);

            test.put("Values",mainMap);

            System.out.println(mainMap);
```

Which is printing out the following :

```
{Next=1234, ICCI={Master Card Credit Card=523951, Visa Debit card=[421323, 421630, 455451, 469375], Master Debit Card=5399, Visa Credit Card=447747}}
```

As I have expected. But in this map, I need to search for some values in the map, say for example `455451`. If doing so I should get output as :

`Visa Debit card, ICCI`.

Is it possible to do a search over the maps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing to do: use generics fully for your maps, rather than raw types. That'll make it much easier to understand your code to start with...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But in this map, I need to search for some values in the map, say for example 455451.

Basically you'll need to iterate over all key/value pairs:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().contains(targetValue)) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Obviously that's not terribly efficient - if you need to do this a lot, you'll probably want to create a reverse map as well, and keep the two in sync.

You might also want to look at [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s `Multimap` types.

Comment: I'm getting an error message as : `BankIdentification.java:30: error: incompatible types` on line `Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()`

Comment: @GroovyUser: You shouldn't if you make your map variable strongly typed to start with.

Comment: Alright, I'm getting confused here, My result map in which I want to search looks like this :`[Values={ICCI={Master Card Credit Card=523951, Visa Debit card=[421323, 421630, 455451, 469375], Master Debit Card=5399, Visa Credit Card=447747}}]`, so does this belong to `Map<String, Map>` right? But I'm getting the same error! :(

Comment: @GroovyUser: The maps you've shown in your question *should* be declared as `Map<String, List<Integer>>`. If you would stop using raw types (e.g. in `Map<String, Map>` in your comment) your life would be a lot simpler, and your question would be a lot clearer.